# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullCalendar' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Hi I'm using fullCalendar jQuery plugin. This code is written based on https://www.drupal.org/node/1345028#comment-5258592

I got issue:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullCalendar' of undefined

What's wrong? Why this chaining doesn't work?

I wanted to make when user clicks on a day (dayClick), go to arbitrary date (gotoDate) and changes view (changeView)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: 
      {
        center: 'month,basicDay'
      },
      defaultView: 'month',
      dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view){
// here what's wrong ↓            
           $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date).fullCalendar('changeView', 'basicDay');



      }
    });
});
```

Comment: that last } is not needed as I can see

Comment: This } was from upper code which I didn't insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive your second call to fullCalendar in line below causes this

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date).fullCalendar('changeView', 'basicDay');
```

Maybe try this or something similar:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'basicDay');
```

Comment: Thank you
`$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'basicDay');` works!